# Action mailer not Working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the Action Mailer first time. I have a mailer Sendmail , and controller books . I am trying to send mail to the user at the time of new  user created . The user is created but Mail is not sent to the user. Why?

Mailer:

```ruby
 class Sendmail < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "kavivel316@gmail.com"
 def send_email(book)
 @book = book
 mail( :to => @book.emailid,
  :subject => 'Thanks for signing up for our amazing app' )
 end
 end
```

send_email.erb

```ruby
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Thanks for signing up, <%= @book.firstname %>!</h1>
 <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day! Now sign in and do
  awesome things!</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

books_controller.rb

```ruby
  def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  name=params[:book][:photo].original_filename
  if @book.save
  Sendmail.send_email(@book).deliver
  redirect_to(@book, :notice => 'User created')
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

environment.rb

```ruby
 require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

  # Initialize the Rails application.
  Rails.application.initialize!
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :user_name => 'kavivel316@gmail.com',
 :password => '*********',
  :domain => 'gmail.com',
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 :port => 25,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Try port 587. BTW, is it a good idea to post your password here?

Comment: I tried it but not working what about the environment.rb file may i have to do any changes in it?

Comment: @user3804139 change your password for gmail!

Comment: can you look into your development.rb or production.rb(in which environment you are working) file, check this line is present or not  in that file   `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`

Answer (score 0):

Change this
     `:user_name => 'kavivel316@gmail.com',`
like this
     `:user_name => 'kavivel316',`

Comment: This might answer the question but it would help if you made a better effort at explaining your answer. As it stands right now, your answer is in the Low Quality Queue.

Answer (score 0):

In environment file change config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors value

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

this will raise an exception if the mailer can't send the mail.